# Symfony2.1: The CSRF token is invalid. Only in browser, PHPUnit WebTestCase works without error

Tags: forms, symfony, phpunit, csrf, csrf-protection

How can I debug why in all my browsers I got **The CSRF token is invalid** error, but when I test same form with Functional test it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I commented my config.yml as below, everything started working? so new question is: What is wrong with commented part of this configuration?

```
session:
    auto_start:     true
    # cookie_lifetime:   86400
    # cookie_path:       \
    # cookie_domain:     example.com
    # cookie_secure:     true
    # cookie_httponly:   true
```

Answer (score 2):

If you customized the way form renders the inputs check if you added **{{form_rest(form) }}** like in the next example.

Example

```
<form action="{{ path('BloggerBlogBundle_contact') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.name) }}
    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
    {{ form_row(form.subject) }}
    {{ form_row(form.body) }}

    {{ form_rest(form) }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: i got only {{ form_widget(form) }} in template. token is visible in html source

Answer (score 2):

For me disabling secure cookie resolved this problem after upgrading from symfony 2.0.16 to 2.1.6:

```
session:
    cookie_lifetime:   3600
    cookie_path:       \
    cookie_domain:     .%base_domain%
    cookie_secure:     false
    cookie_httponly:   true
```

Answer (score -5):

You can Use @csrf_exempt decorator to excempt csrf token for this you have to import

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

then write @csrf_exempt before your view

this will work properly :)

Comment: This question is about Symfony2 and not Python or Django.